# Displaying limit for selectable options

Tags: gui-design, lists, user-centered-design

### **Case**

In our software, we have a list of modules/options that the user can enable or disable.

[image: List of selectable modules]

Each enabled module has a severe performance impact on the CPU, so to avoid crashes, we decided to hard-limit the amount of modules the user can enable. I was looking for ways to display this limit.

### **Method 1: Label with "X/10"**

[image: Display label with limit]

A very simple method would be to display a label with the hard limit maximum and the current selected amount of modules. The user cannot exceed the amount at any time.

**Pros**

- Simple to create
- Instantly clear how many modules are activated
- Instantly clear what the limit is

**Cons**

- No clear reason why limit exists

### **Method 2: "Load"-bar**

[image]

Another option i had in mind was displaying a progressbar that would act as a "CPU load" indicator. If more modules are enabled, the progressbar would fill up and change color. In the background, the hardlimit still exists.

**Pros**

- Visually more pleasing
- Clear reason for limit=

**Cons**

- Hardlimit number is unknown for user
- I work at NASA and my super-PC can only activate 7 items, just like my crappy old laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You could just place a question-mark icon next to the "(3/10)" of option one and explain the user what that number means and why its limited with a tooltip he sees after clicking it.